# Simulating RFID coil with FEMM

Tags: simulation, rfid, femm

Is it possible to simulate planar coil printed on a PCB with FEMM?
The only idea that come into my mind is to have 2n (if n is the number of turns) regions, each region represents a copper trace and has one turn (half traces have positive turn and half traces have negative turn). Something like this:
[image: snapshot]

Is this correct approach?
If yes should this be solved as a magnetic problem or as a current flow problem?
Is what I draw something that is really a planar RFID coil in 3D? I can't seem to understand how those lines are closing.

Answer (score 1):

This approach worked perfectly fine for me. I did such a simulation with FEMM and I got reasonable results.

The LUA scripting in FEMM even allows you to move the geometry between simulations, in order to find the best solution.

Comment: I edited question a bit and if I am on the good way I can provide also the simulation results and everything ...

Comment: It should be solved as Magnetics Problem.